# convolution that takes a function as kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to experiment with convolution where the kernel is not constant, but dependents on the patch of the input (I'll call it filter to differentiate) and is calculated by a function `f`.

So what I need is something like:

```
conv2d :: 
    R^(batch x height x width x in_channel) x 
    f : 
        R ^ (filter_height x filter_width x in_channels) 
        -> R ^ (filter_height x filter_width x in_channels x out_channels)
    -> out
```

What I don't want is to just evaluate `f` for every patch in the convolution. It's critical for my application that `f` just produces the filter for every patch of the input and then the filter gets applied to the patch.

Is this somehow hackable with tf and if not, is there a reasonable way to extend tf to provide me with the needed functionality? I have never written CUDA, but I don't shy away from it.

Comment: So for every pixel in the image you would have a different filter? Then would the tensor of filters be something like `(height, width, filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels)` (assuming `SAME` padding, for example)?

Comment: yeah, but they are not arbitrary but defined by f, which is a simple MLP.

Comment: Is the filter size known at graph creation time? And in that case, what kind of size would that be? (I am considering whether it is reasonable to loop through this size to create the graph).

Comment: yeah, the filter is known at graph creating time and should not be different from normal CNN-kernel sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

As suggested by the OP, given the complexity of the operation it may become more tractable by using [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

mode_same = True  # True to make output same size as input
BATCH_SIZE = 10
HEIGHT = 100
WIDTH = 200
IN_CHANNELS = 3
FILTER_HEIGHT = 10
FILTER_WIDTH = 7
OUT_CHANNELS = 5

def make_img_filters(img):
    # Dummy filters function
    img_shape = tf.shape(img)
    img_height = img_shape[0]
    img_width = img_shape[1]
    img_ch = img_shape[2]
    filters_shape = (img_height, img_width, FILTER_HEIGHT, FILTER_WIDTH, img_ch, OUT_CHANNELS)
    return tf.zeros(filters_shape, dtype=img.dtype)

def filter_img(img, mode_same=True):
    img_filters = make_img_filters(img)
    # Shapes
    img_shape = tf.shape(img)
    img_height = img_shape[0]
    img_width = img_shape[1]
    filters_shape = tf.shape(img_filters)
    filter_height = filters_shape[2]
    filter_width = filters_shape[3]
    # Image margins to pad or crop
    margin_bottom = filter_height // 2
    margin_top = tf.maximum(filter_height - margin_bottom - 1, 0)
    margin_right = filter_width // 2
    margin_left = tf.maximum(filter_width - margin_right - 1, 0)
    # Pad or crop depending on "same" or "valid" mode
    img_pad = img
    img_filters_crop = img_filters
    if mode_same:
        img_pad = tf.pad(img, [[margin_top, margin_bottom], [margin_left, margin_right], [0, 0]])
        img_height += margin_top + margin_bottom
        img_width += margin_left + margin_right
    else:
        img_filters_crop = img_filters[margin_top:img_height - margin_bottom, margin_left:img_width - margin_right]
    # Make tensor of image patches
    # This could be replaced with tf.while_loop and tf.TensorArray
    img_extend = tf.stack([img_pad[i:(img_height - (FILTER_HEIGHT - i - 1))] for i in range(FILTER_HEIGHT)], axis=2)
    img_extend = tf.stack([img_extend[:, i:(img_width - (FILTER_WIDTH - i - 1))] for i in range(FILTER_WIDTH)], axis=3)
    # Compute "convolution" result
    img_result = tf.einsum('hwpqc,hwpqcd->hwd', img_extend, img_filters_crop)
    # Or with multiplication and reduction
    img_result = tf.reduce_sum(img_extend[..., tf.newaxis] * img_filters_crop, axis=(2, 3))
    return img_result

# Input
imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, HEIGHT, WIDTH, IN_CHANNELS])
filters = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, HEIGHT, WIDTH, FILTER_HEIGHT, FILTER_WIDTH, IN_CHANNELS, OUT_CHANNELS])
# Compute "convolution" with mapping
result = tf.map_fn(lambda img: filter_img(img, mode_same), imgs)

# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    imgs_random = np.random.random((BATCH_SIZE, HEIGHT, WIDTH, IN_CHANNELS))
    filters_random = np.random.random((BATCH_SIZE, HEIGHT, WIDTH, FILTER_HEIGHT, FILTER_WIDTH, IN_CHANNELS, OUT_CHANNELS))
    value = sess.run(result, feed_dict={imgs: imgs_random, filters: filters_random})
    print(value.shape)
    # (10, 91, 194, 5) with mode_same=False, (10, 100, 200, 5) with mode_same=True
```

---

If I am understanding you correctly, this should do the operation you want. It may not be the most efficient method possible, but I am not not sure whether it can be done much faster with standard TensorFlow operations.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

mode_same = False  # True to make output same size as input
BATCH_SIZE = 10
HEIGHT = 100
WIDTH = 200
IN_CHANNELS = 3
FILTER_HEIGHT = 10
FILTER_WIDTH = 7
OUT_CHANNELS = 5
# Input
imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, HEIGHT, WIDTH, IN_CHANNELS])
filters = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, HEIGHT, WIDTH, FILTER_HEIGHT, FILTER_WIDTH, IN_CHANNELS, OUT_CHANNELS])
# Shapes
imgs_shape = tf.shape(imgs)
img_height = imgs_shape[1]
img_width = imgs_shape[2]
filters_shape = tf.shape(filters)
filter_height = filters_shape[3]
filter_width = filters_shape[4]
# Image margins to pad or crop
margin_bottom = filter_height // 2
margin_top = tf.maximum(filter_height - margin_bottom - 1, 0)
margin_right = filter_width // 2
margin_left = tf.maximum(filter_width - margin_right - 1, 0)
# Pad or crop depending on "same" or "valid" mode
imgs_pad = imgs
filters_crop = filters
if mode_same:
    imgs_pad = tf.pad(imgs, [[0, 0], [margin_top, margin_bottom], [margin_left, margin_right], [0, 0]])
    img_height += margin_top + margin_bottom
    img_width += margin_left + margin_right
else:
    filters_crop = filters[:, margin_top:img_height - margin_bottom, margin_left:img_width - margin_right]
# Make tensor of image patches
# This could be replaced with tf.while_loop and tf.TensorArray
imgs_extend = tf.stack([imgs_pad[:, i:(img_height - (FILTER_HEIGHT - i - 1))] for i in range(FILTER_HEIGHT)], axis=3)
imgs_extend = tf.stack([imgs_extend[:, :, i:(img_width - (FILTER_WIDTH - i - 1))] for i in range(FILTER_WIDTH)], axis=4)
# Compute "convolution" result
result = tf.einsum('ahwpqc,ahwpqcd->ahwd', imgs_extend, filters_crop)
# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    imgs_random = np.random.random((BATCH_SIZE, HEIGHT, WIDTH, IN_CHANNELS))
    filters_random = np.random.random((BATCH_SIZE, HEIGHT, WIDTH, FILTER_HEIGHT, FILTER_WIDTH, IN_CHANNELS, OUT_CHANNELS))
    value = sess.run(result, feed_dict={imgs: imgs_random, filters: filters_random})
    print(value.shape)
    # (10, 91, 194, 5) with mode_same=False, (10, 100, 200, 5) with mode_same=True
```

Comment: I hope this works...i am a bit wary about the memory requirements for this implementation. Also, my filters are defined by a function, so there are not that many additional weights to train, but that should be trivial to add.

Comment: @Leander Yes, I'm not sure how big batches/images/filters this may handle... It does feel like it should be possible to do something similar to broadcasting but I couldn't think of it... Feel free to comment after you have made some experiments (or leave the answer unaccepted if it's not good enough or you want to wait for others).

Comment: And you even throw in handling of convolution mode. Very nice.

Comment: hmm, I think I have identified a problem. Because I have a function that computes the filter for the specific patch, I have (after applying the function) a tensor `[-1, image_height, image_width, filter_height, filter_width, image_c, filter_out_c]`. I would expect that to blow up my memory pretty fast.

Comment: @jdehesa I think I have a (preliminary) solution, I do everything in a `map_fn`. Evaluating `f` to get the filter and multiplying it with the image. So no `einsum` and filter-tensor. If you edit your solution, i'll accept it. It's still slow, but not unbelievable slow.

Comment: @Leander Right, so you have a different filter for each pixel _of each image_, that probably makes more sense. I have changed the original code accordingly and added the version with `tf.map_fn` (you can still use einsum or product and reduction for the "convolution", performance seems to be the same).